# Can't debug my Activator/Play application with eclipse after migrating to Play 2.3.8

Tags: playframework-2.3

I'm migrating my project from play 2.2.3 to 2.3.8. This went good so far with a little bumps on the road. The only remaining issue is that I just can't run Activator/Play in debug mode. It runs fine without debug though.

I'm using:
`activator -jvm-debug 9999 run`

My app runs fine and Eclipse debug binds to to port 9999 as expected. But unfortunately it never stops for a checkpoint.

My impression is that the debug is only activated for the JVM that runs Activator, but not the JVM that runs my app, although I have no evidence for this, since my knowledge about Activator isn't advanced enough (I just read somewhere that activator starts a new JVM for each app).

Answer (score 4):

This is because Activator / Play 2.3.8 performs forking of the run process without copying of the debug options. You can cancel forking in your build.sbt:
`fork in run := false`
Or alternatively you can specify the Java debugging options there:
`javaOptions in run +=
"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999"`
With the latter you don't need the -jvm-debug in the activator command line.

Comment: Thanks jacool! Unfortunately I gave up the migration to 2.3.8 for now. It had to many obstacles. It needs more time than I have right now. But I'll continue migrating at one point in future. :) Therefore, unfortunately I can't confirm your solution. Maybe someone else can?

Comment: I did got the first one working in intellij. When you modify "fork in run := false" you can NOT use the "activator ui" command. This will re-add fork in run := true. Instead you need to run "activator -jvm-debug 9999 run". For the alternate solution you just need to run "activator run".  Then in intellij you can setup a remote debug configuration on port 9999. Your break points will hit after starting the new remote debug configuration you created

Answer (score 0):

I set the 
    *fork in run := false* 
in my build.sbt.

It did not stop on my breakpoint in the run() method of my Controller subclass. Although later breakpoints are hit when I hit a URL and a RESTful service is hit.

Might this just be a timing issue? I am probably not fast enough to get the debug start, as it uses Standard (socket attach) method so Play has to start before the listener is there. Wondering how you debug the methods that get hit when startup occurs?